# Heroku Backend not Communicating with Frontend

Tags: http, heroku, deployment, heroku-api

I am relatively new with deploying web applications so please bear with me!

I have successfully deployed a Flask API Backend on Heroku. I also have a frontend website and when I use localhost, the application communicates with the deployed API perfectly. However, when I deploy the frontend onto Heroku or AWS Amplify, it fails to communicate with the Backend API. Looking at the Heroku logs, it appears that it is not actually receiving the request so I was wondering how I would make it so that the frontend can communicate with the backend.

Comment: Hello, have you added the environment variables correcty in production ?

Comment: @JérômeW are there any specific environment variables I need to add?

Comment: I mean you have a .env in local, so you need to add it too in production